# How to concatenate and group rows in large BigQuery table with "Resources exceeded" problems

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a single field table with 1.1 billion rows in BigQuery.

Table properties:

1. One field where Field name - id and Field Type - String
2. Table total size - 8.3GB

I would like to create a new as follow:

1. The first column is a UUID field using GENERATE_UUID()
2. The second column, id_str, which is 25,000 id records concatenated into this column with comma separated id values

I have tried different solutions but keep running into

> "Resources exceeded"

Is there a smart way around this limitation? Any other approach to solve my problem inside BigQuery?

The code I have at the moment that generates the above-mentioned error

```
SELECT
  GENERATE_UUID() as batch_id,
  STRING_AGG(id) as ids_str
from
  (
  WITH vars AS (
  SELECT 25000 as rec_count
)
  SELECT
    cast(ceiling(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()  / 25000) as int64) as batch_count,
    25000 as rec_count,
    cast(id as string) as id
  FROM
    tbl_profile
)
group by rec_count
```

Comment: Why would you want to store such a large string?  Why not have a lookup table for each table to a guid?

Comment: To add to @GordonLinoff question is the error message only "Resources exceeded"? or there are other details. Also in your SQL you provide the `SELECT` part only is this the part who has the issue? What happens if you limit the inner SQL with a `WHERE` after the `FROM tbl_profile`

Comment: The purpose of the table is to create 40k batch jobs with 25k ids in each job record and a unique UUID field. I want to create a table with one row for each batch job with a string of 25k ids so that they can be served quickly. 

The BigQuery result table will be exported to CloudSQL which will distribute the jobs one by one to the workers. I just want to split up the 1B rows into 25k chunks but keep running into "Resources exceeded" since you cant sort data sets that large. I don't know how to create 25k chunks without using sorting

I want to keep all my SQL data processing logic in BQ

Comment: I meant "without using row number logic", and not sorting in answer above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any other approach to solve my problem inside BigQuery?

If your use-case allows you to relax a little requirements so instead of

```
The second column to be 25,000 id concatenated into one column
```

it would be

```
The second column to be about (close to) 25,000 id concatenated into one column
```

In this case below (for BigQuery Standard SQL) can/should work well for you

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  GENERATE_UUID() AS batch_id,
  COUNT(1) batch_size,
  STRING_AGG(id) AS ids_str
FROM (
  SELECT
    CAST((cnt * RAND()) / 25000 + 0.5 AS INT64) AS batch_count,
    CAST(id AS STRING) AS id
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) cnt FROM `project.dataset.table`)
)
GROUP BY batch_count
```

this should produce result as below

[image]

As you can see here, number of id's in each row not exact 25,000 but close enough to it

Hope this can be an option for you

Comment: Your assumption is correct and about 25k batch size is perfectly fine as explained a  little more in my answer above.

This solution is perfect and will help me group & concatenate without using row number logic. Thanks again for your contribution to this community. Hope you have a great day.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please also consider voting up the answer o)